# Correct aspect ratio in VLC run from a console

Tags: console, video, vlc

When I play a video with `cvlc` from a console (without X) the aspect ratio is wrong; the video is stretched to fill the entire screen instead of using a letterbox format (black bars). How can I keep the aspect ratio?